# gremlin query to find maximum two level edges from vertice

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3

I have vertices - A, B, C, D, E, F
and I have edges - E1(A-B), E2(B-C), E3(A-C), E4(A-D), E5(E-F)

now I want to identify maximum two level of edges from vertices A like below

- E1(A-B) E2(B-C)
- E3(A-C) E2(B-C)
- E4(A-D)

If someone help me identify gremlin query for this really appreciated

EDITED

Here is a set of steps that creates the sample graph:

```
g.addV('A').as('a').
  addV('B').as('b').
  addV('C').as('c').
  addV('D').as('d').
  addV('E').as('e').
  addV('F').as('f').
  addE('E1').from('a').to('b').
  addE('E2').from('b').to('c').
  addE('E3').from('a').to('c').
  addE('E4').from('a').to('d').
  addE('E5').from('e').to('f').iterate()
```

Comment: It's unfortunate that this was closed as the question makes perfect sense to anyone familiar with Apache TinkerPop and Gremlin. Perhaps edit the question to add a few addV and addE steps that create the example graph.

Comment: I went ahead and made the edit for you and suggested the question be re-opened.

Answer (score 1):

Using the sample graph added to the question you can use a simple `repeat` query with an added `emit` step to find the paths you are looking for that start at vertex A.

```
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('A').
               repeat(outE().inV().simplePath()).
               times(2).emit().
               path().
                 by(label)


==>[A,E1,B]
==>[A,E3,C]
==>[A,E4,D]
==>[A,E1,B,E2,C]
```